# Is there a unique solution for this equation..?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to solve the below mentioned equation and try to find a unique solution for $\epsilon$ for the range between (-1,1) in terms of $n$.

$$\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{(2{\alpha_j} + 1)( \alpha_j -1)}{{\bigg[(\alpha_j - 1) \bigg((2{\alpha_j}+3) - \epsilon(2{\alpha_j}+1)\bigg) \bigg]\,\,\,}^{2}}  = 0
\end{equation}
$$

where

$\alpha_j=\cos\frac{2{\pi}j}{n}$.

With simulations, I can see that there's a unique solution for $\epsilon$ when $\epsilon$ is in (-1,1) and I need to find that as an expression in terms of $n$. Any suggestions

Comment: I removed the (soft-question) tag, which is for questions that don't admit a definitive answer. Please read the tag summaries that are offered in the tag selection menu when selecting tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your sum has following closed form:

$$\frac{\left( n-1 \right)  \left( 2\,\cosh \left( 2\,{\frac {\pi }{n}}
 \right) +1 \right)}  {\left( \cosh \left( 2\,{\frac {\pi }{n}} \right) 
-1 \right)  \left( 2\,\cosh \left( 2\,{\frac {\pi }{n}} \right) +
3-\epsilon \, \left( 2\,\cosh \left( 2\,{\frac {\pi }{n}} \right) +1
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}$$

So when this expression is equal to $0$ ,  $\epsilon$ may be an arbitrary number.

Comment: Since $j$ is not an imaginary unit here, can we use the above mentioned closed form for this problem ? Is there any other way to solve this problem?