# How to solve this equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the equation given below for values for $\epsilon$?

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (2{\alpha_{j}}+1) ~~ \prod_{k=1,~k\neq j}^{n-1} \bigg(({\alpha_{k}}-1){\Big((2{\alpha_{k}}+3) + {\epsilon}(2{\alpha_{k}}+1)\Big)}^{2}\bigg) = 0
$$

where $\alpha_i = \cos{\dfrac{2\pi i}{n}}$, where $n$ is an even integer and $n \geqslant 8$. ($j$ is NOT the imaginary unit).

Comment: Is this the same as your earlier question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76293/is-there-a-unique-solution-for-this-equation ?

Comment: What do you get when $n$ is 2 or 3?

Comment: @ Gerry - Yes. It's related to that problem. Need help to solve this or a method to solve this one..

Comment: @ GEdgar - I haven't tried when $n$ is 2 or 3 since my problem is basically to find the behavior when $n$ is greater than or equal to 8.